# Is there a way in c++ to make it so that the program runs as long as there are new values introduced?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm wondering if there is a way in c++ to make a "while (there still are new values) {...}"
By that I mean that, if you insert 6/50/400 values then press enter, it does the while operation 6/50/400 times, for each of the new values.
Try to keep it simple if you can, I'm just a newcomer, and thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Oh, right! Sorry guys, I didn't know there are books about C++. My bad! :D

Comment: no offense, but you are better off [reading a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of trying to learn C++ by asking questions here.

Comment: I agree, reading a book or some other good reference first will give you a better overview of C++, including flow control of course.

Comment: If he's using spaces to separate the data, then `cin >> var` will not directly load all of them into the variable and he might indeed need a loop or another approach to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `std::cin` method from the `iostream` library returns true when it can read an input and false when it tries to read but there's nothing more to read. So you can use `while(cin >> bar)` and it will read input until it finds an EOF character (either from you pressing CTRL+D in the console or from reaching the end of a file redirected to stdin)